# How to move my own archive file from Jenkins system to artifactory

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, build

Thanks in advance! I am new to Jenkins and Maven. Please clarify my query for better understanding.

After the build `war` getting deployed from Jenkins system to Artifactory location (created under the tags `<distributionManagement>`/`<snapshotRepository>` in parent `pom.xml`). How this is happening without any scripts configured in Jenkins?

Can I do the same for my own archive file to place in Artifactory from Jenkins system after the build? I exposed some `jar`s and getting archived in Jenkins system during the build and expecting same to be placed in Artifactory after the build same as how `war` is getting placed in Artifactory.

### PLugin details for deploy:

I have many webapps and parent/super pom.xml.All wars are getting deployed in artifactory repository.Now looking for solution to deploy common folder also (ProvidedDependencies_${version}  - Created during build time) .

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>artifactory</repositoryId>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <url>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</url>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <file>/ProvidedDependencies_${version}</file>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `mvn deploy` deploys the artifact(s) that has (or have) been built during the current run to your local repository, *Artifactory* in your case. See [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

A Jenkins [Maven 2/3 project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) or a  [Free-style software project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) with an appropriate build step can be configured to invoke `mvn deploy`.

Comment: Is there a way by adding something in pom.xml to deploy the artifacts created during build from jenkin system to artifactory repository .i mean without using mvn deploy comand

Comment: @user439587 Why do you think you need that? The `deploy` goal of the [Maven Deploy Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/) is bound to the `deploy` phase by default → Run `mvn help:effective-pom` in your project's directory and see `<plugins>/<plugin>/<artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin/.../<phase>deploy/.../<goal>deploy`. And this has nothing to do with Jenkins. From a more global perspective Jenkins is "just" a build trigger system that's wrapped around (Maven) builds (in your case).

Comment: I added details above with plugin code, can you please help to deploy comon folder (contains provided scope jars).Common folder got created as expected in jenkin system but deploy to artifactory repository not happenig